# Node.js+AWS S3: Upload new file and create a new folder if doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am able to upload a file to AWS S3.

But, lets say I have uploaded a file to my bucket with the key: `myfolder\filename.pdf`,

It doesn't create the folder `myfolder`, and the name of the new file in S3 (also when downloaded) is `myfolder_filename.pdf` (it replaces backslash with underscore).

My questions are:
1. How can I determine the downloaded file's name?
2. How can I tell AWS that I want it to create new folder? maybe than the downloaded filename will be just `filename.pdf`.

Maybe the problem is that I used backslash and not frontslash? (i used path.join)

Thanks!

Comment: There's no concept of "folder" in S3. From docs: "In Amazon S3, buckets and objects are the primary resources, and objects are stored in buckets. Amazon S3 has a flat structure instead of a hierarchy like you would see in a file system. However, for the sake of organizational simplicity, the Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept as a means of grouping objects. Amazon S3 does this by using a shared name prefix for objects (that is, objects have names that begin with a common string). Object names are also referred to as key names."

Comment: That's sucks because when I download the file I'm getting the whole object path. How can I solve this issue if there are not folders? (BTW, in the S3 panel, there is a button "create folder" that actually create a folder. I want that every user will have it's own "space"/"folder".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you have to send the "folder/filename" for the "Key" property in AWS sdk S3 call. S3 will create the folder if it doesn't exist based on the key you are sending.

You have to pass the key as "myfolder/filename.pdf" . The slash should be "/"

Comment: The code is not the issue here. It's an AWS S3 question. See @Victor answer

Comment: The only thing you need to add  is "/" instead of "\" in the  S3 key

Comment: You gotta be kidding me... as I thought "Maybe the problem is that I used backslash and not frontslash? (i used path.join)". but path.join puts backslash, what is the best way?

Comment: I am not kidding here . trying to help you out

Comment: So what is the best way to do that? `path.join` puts backslash

Comment: You can use normal string concatenation like var key= foldername+"/" +filename;

Comment: Not sure there is a better way than this. You can simply write a function which will return the key based on the folder and filename as inputs